# facebook extended permission 'read_stream' not showing

Tags: facebook

I have the following code for getting the permissions from facebook login about the extended permission for user when they login .

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {

        console.log(response);
      });


  } else {
    // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
      console.log('you are not authorized');
  }
}, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,email'});


and 

<fb:login-button data-scope="read_stream,email" >
</fb:login-button>
```

Its not showing extended permissions during login for new user !

Comment: If your app is using Graph API v2.0 and is not reviewed yet, you'll not be able to request `read_stream` permission! Try it with the admin user of the respective app, this should work.

Comment: yes i have all permissions for admin , but not for other user , can u suggest what should i do , so i can allow read_stream for other user !

Comment: can u suggest , so user can take permission from login?

Answer (score 1):

Also note that even though it is not mentioned in the docs that they do not allow access to the read stream permission if the platform has a native app (ios, desktop, web, android, windows phone). You might get around it by making an app for Firefox OS and use that permission in your other apps to (just a suggestion did not try it my self and Facebook app review might reject this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your app for review, as described in the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login Otherwise you'll not be able to use extended permissions.

Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Answer (score 0):

When read_stream is unapproved, Facebook says :

> The read_stream permission is only approved for apps that let people
>   use Facebook on platforms where Facebook is not already available. If
>   you're building an app on Android and iOS, for example, you won't be
>   approved for this permission. Web, Desktop and TV apps will also not
>   be granted this permission.

Answer (score -1):

I think this link may help you:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
There no way to pass permission via login form for a facebook app created after April 30th, 2014.

Comment: That's not correct! It is possible, but only after a review of the app by Facebook.

Comment: For an app which are developeing. Im sure that you cant get accpet from facebook team. I already tried submitted some permissions.

Comment: You don't need a review unless you're just developing/testing with admin users of the app. You can submit the app once the development is done.